# Thread safe class for holding a access token in Java

Tags: java

I would like to make a `Token` class that should hold an access token. However once the token expires the next time its used the token should be refreshed. The problem is that this needs to be handled in a thread safe way. As long as `isExpired` is false everyone should be able to access the token. But as soon as the token is expired only one call to update the token should be made and others trying to read the token has to wait.

What I have so far is the following:

```
public class Token {
  private boolean isExpired = true;
  private String token = "";
  private final AccessTokenClient tokenRetriever;

  public Token(AccessTokenClient tokenRetriever) {
    this.tokenRetriever = tokenRetriever;
  }

  public String getToken() {
    // If isExpired true
    // Use tokenRetriever to get a new token
    // Only one request to getToken should try to update the token, others trying to call getToken has to wait.
    return null;
  }
}
```

My questions is: What is the idiomatic way of implementing a access token cache like this in Java 8?

Comment: all threads should share the same token?

Comment: what mechanism updates `isExpired` to true?

Comment: Yes all threads should share the same token. If a call to an endpoint with the token returns 403 it should set the token to expired. And then retry, when it tries to get the token again it will see the token is expired and the token will be refreshed. This is my plan anyways.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the most basic example I could think of:

```
public class Token {

    private final AccessTokenClient tokenRetriever;
    private final Object monitor;
    private volatile boolean isExpired = true;
    private volatile String token = "";

    public Token(AccessTokenClient tokenRetriever) {
        this.tokenRetriever = tokenRetriever;
        this.monitor = new Object();
    }

    public String getToken() {
        if (this.isExpired) {
            synchronized (this.monitor) {
                // intended double check!
                if (this.isExpired) {
                    this.token = this.tokenRetriever.retrieveToken();
                    this.isExpired = false;
                }
            }
        }

        return this.token;
    }
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't be better `public synchronized String getToken() { ... }`?

Comment: Unless they have done something over the years to fix it, double-checked locking doesn't work reliably. Synchronize the whole method or remove the outer "if" block. https://www.cs.umd.edu/~pugh/java/memoryModel/DoubleCheckedLocking.html

Comment: The pattern used here is called "Double-checked locking". Beware that for this pattern to work, `token` and `isExpired` *must* be `volatile`.

Comment: @TadHarrison the `volatile` keyword fixes it.

Comment: I understand. For sake of clarity, declaring the method `synchronized` would be better since the double check would be unnecessary and I'd get a meaning of the piece of code at first sight. Here I have to stop for a while and get the idea of the double check. The right question would be: "How much performance I save for the costs of the clarity".

Comment: @Etienne Miret, Got it. I hadn't seen that they were defined as `volatile`.

Comment: @Nikolas, I agree. Unless this provides a substantial performance improvement, it introduces many places for a developer to fat finger things (e.g. forgetting the `volatile`). Let it prove itself to be a bottleneck first, then tune it.

Comment: @TadHarrison the link you posted is pre-jdk5, so a *long* time ago. the "new" java memory model was introduced to help with these kind of issues back in 2004, so 15 years ago.

Comment: @eis I still link to that very page each time I see a developer forget the `volatile` keyword. While old, I believe it is still instructive.

Comment: @EtienneMiret have you noticed that on the bottom of the page it says "If Helper is an immutable object, such that all of the fields of Helper are final, then double-checked locking will work without having to use volatile fields. The idea is that a reference to an immutable object (such as a String or an Integer) should behave in much the same way as an int or float; reading and writing references to immutable objects are atomic.", so volatile shouldn't even be required.